# RESTEASY004687: Closing a class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient43Engine instance for you

Tags: java, graphql, quarkus

Actually, I am using java quarkus to request to graphql which has dynamic url. But the issue is after the request is completed I am getting this warning:
`WARN  [org.jbo.res.cli.jax.i18n] (Finalizer) RESTEASY004687: Closing a class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient43Engine instance for you. Please close clients yourself.`  Can someone have some advice?

I tried closing the client but it didn't have .close() method available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you use `RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().z().build(YourClientIface.class)`
In this case all you need make your interface `extends Closeable`
And wrap your client creation and usage into **try** section like:

```
try (YourClientIface client = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder().build(YourClientIface.class)) {
        client.getSmth();
}
```

Your client will be closed automatically